# Cannot edit Document Template of Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-library, excel-online

today I tried to change my custom Document Template for one of my Sharepoint Librarys.
*(So everytime someone click on new Excel File, he opens this template)*
Unfortunately its not longer possible to modify the file, when I klick the Edit Button nothings happening. Problems occur on both Edge and IE, but the IE throws the following Error: [image: Error Message in IE 11]

Currently i am using IE 11 so that should be no problem.

Before writing this post I checked that I am still Owner of the Page.
**All other Files can be open in the Browser like expected, the problem occurs only when editing a template file**

Here in Edge when I try to click the Link nothings happening
[image: Advanced Settings of Library]

****************EDIT****************
I encountered another unexpected behaviour.
When I click on the [Edit Template] Buttons nothings happening, but when I right click and "Open in new Tab" the file isn't opened but downloaded as a copy which isn't connected to Sharepoint

Comment: EDIT: Please see my post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **Add template** option shown below?

[image]

You can refer to this article [Many ways to use document templates](https://sharepointmaven.com/5-ways-to-store-and-reuse-document-templates-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hello, thx for the Answer but I defined my Template as Standard Template for Excel Files and not another extra template

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if the URL of the template is right or re-upload the document template**

1.Sign in the site collection as an admin

2.Go to **Site settings** page >> click on **Site conent types** under the **Web Designer Galleries**

3.Go to the Site Content Types page, click the **Document** content type

[image]

4.Click on **Advanced settings**

- On the "**Enter the URL of an existing document template**" textbox to check the template URL is right
- Then, please select the "**Upload a new document templat**e" checkbox, and upload this template again

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello tank you for your answer. Could you give me the correct synatx how to check if the file exists?